# Passing Class arguments through RMI

Tags: java, class, rmi, corba

I'm supposed to invoke a method requiring a `Class<T>` argument on a remote object through RMI. I have to admit I'm not very familiar with RMI or CORBA.

The target method interface implemented by the remote object is:

```
public <T extends Enum<? extends Foo<?>> > void doSomething(String str, Class<T> enumClazz);
```

When I pass a class as argument in the RMI call, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy196.doSomething(java.lang.String, javax.rmi.CORBA.ClassDesc)
    at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:284)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:855)
```

Why is the object transformed to a `javax.rmi.CORBA.ClassDesc`? FYI the Java EE container is a WebSphere Application server 8.0.0.5.

Comment: please show us your client code

Comment: Please also show the complete stack trace and the command line you used to invoke 'rmic -iiop'.

Comment: In fact I can't make any sense of this. What is `Foo`? Shouldn't it just be `<T extends Enum<T>>`? Why doesn't the method throw `RemoteException`?

Comment: In the absence of any response I am voting to close as not a real question.